# Weavy: Webhook for new Messages

Tags: weavy

has anyone managed to setup a webhook for new messages? My goal would be that every time a new message is received by a user, a webhook is triggered which I can receive in make.com to also send an email to the specific user.

I have managed to successfully set up the webhook, however when I send messages between users, it is not triggered..

It is currently set up the following way:

`{ "id": 1, "payload_url": "https://hook.eu1.make.com/9eccb5spfb7vv63ib2t4d00qsfj72uzw", "triggers": [ "messages", "notifications" ], "is_enabled": true }`

Therefore no messages are arriving in my webhook.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion for troubleshooting would be to check the [deliveries endpoint](https://www.weavy.com/docs/reference/web-api/webhooks#list-webhook-deliveries) to see if Weavy tried to deliver anything to your payload url.

Comment: Unfortunately also the delivery shows as empty.. I get 200 as a response, however the body is empty []..

Answer (score 0):

Along with checking for deliveries, it's good to check that the endpoint receiving the delivery is set up correctly and that you have a Pro or Trial version of the Weavy Product you're using WebHooks with.

If everything looks right there as well, please reach out to me at dave@weavy.com. That way we can make sure to help you get this working! In this case, there was an issue with the Weavy license not having the proper Chat Pro features enabled and it has been resolved.

Thanks for working with us to get to the bottom of this, Jerome. :)